# ASP.NET MVC must match validation attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I cant seem to find the annotation to use that makes sure 2 or more textboxes are the same.

For ex:

```
public class NewPasswordModel
{
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    [MustMatch(Name="NewPassword")] // What is the correct thing to come here.
    public string NewPasswordRep { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the native `CompareAttribute`

```
public class NewPasswordModel
{
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    [Compare("NewPassword")]
    public string NewPasswordRep { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is there an attribute for the opposite? As in, prevent them being the same.

Answer (score 4):

You can install the [DataAnnotationsExtensions.MVC3](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/DataAnnotationsExtensions.MVC3) nuget package, and use the [`EqualToAttribute`](http://dataannotationsextensions.org/EqualTo/Create).

```
public class NewPasswordModel
{
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    [EqualTo("NewPassword")]
    public string NewPasswordRep { get; set; }
}
```

It provides scripts for unobtrusive jQuery validation, so client-side validation will work as well.

Comment: Is there an advantage to this rather than `Compare`?